# c# Best class to hold a list of values to look up after

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary

I have a list of values that i need to check against a constant list to know wheter they are present or not (one by one).

Im using a dictionary buy it doesnt seem logical to have the value two times (key, value)...isnt there any class specialized for this case (and faster if possible)?

Also it would me more reasonable if it could be declared as a constant being a predefined list

Comment: Even `HashSet<T>` isn't going to be significantly faster than `Dictionary<K,V>`.  Prior to `HashSet` being introduced to the BCL in .NET 3.5, I would always use `Dictionary<MyType,bool>` to build a hashtable used only for its set semantics.

Comment: I'd typically use a Dictionary<MyType, object> with all objects set to null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you need a [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx).

Comment: Its there a way to define it as a const? Or a counterpart version that does it?

Comment: No, i mean a value constant from compile time... like const string="test"

Answer (score 2):

Use `HashSet<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

[HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb359438(VS.90).aspx)